# How do I open xiki on emacs?

Tags: emacs, xiki

I installed xiki and I even got it running on emacs, but I closed emacs, and now the xiki page doesn't come up. How do I reopen it? Also, is there a wiki page for xiki? I can't find info anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Just type

```
- welcome/
```

and Ctrl-Enter.  You'll get the welcome menu.

No, there is no wiki page, but if you type

```
- menu/
```

you should get pretty much everything.